# Regarding the installshield's custom dialog

Tags: installshield

Currently I use basic msi project in installshield.
I modify the destinaton dialog and add one checkbox on this dialog.
I want to use this checkbox's value in other place.
So how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the checkbox you created in the dialog and you'll notice it has a Property and Value attribute.   The Property is the name of the property that gets set when you check/uncheck the checkbox.   The Property name should be in ALL CAPS to make it Public.  It should also be listed in the SecureCustomProperties property to make it secure.  ( Can pass from UI to Execute sequence during UAC/Elevated installation scenarios ) .  The Value attribute says what the value of the Property is when it's checked.   The unchecked value is always null/empty/unset.

If you need a different unchecked value you'll have to write a Set Property custom action that gives it a value when it doesn't have a value.

From there you can use it in other places ( such as Registry or XML changes ) by typing [PROPERTYNAME].

Comment: How would I go about creating such a custom action, that only sets the property if it is unset (I removed the property from the properties manager as I want the checkbox to be unchecked by default)? I created a custom set property action, but the property _always_ gets set according to the custom action, no matter what the checkbox state is. 
Any advice would be appreciated..

Comment: Put a condition on the custom action of   Not PROPERTY.  If PROPERTY is null that will evaluate to true and the custom action will fire setting the property.  If PROPERTY has a value (any value)  it will evaluate to false and the custom action will not fire and the property will continue to have the value it already had.

Comment: Thank you so much, the condition was exactly the thing I was trying to figure out - how to evaluate if a property is set. You rock!